# script not working on ksh while working on bash and sh

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

```
ksh xyz.sh gives following error.
abc is symlink to xyz.sh
/sites/utils/local/bin/abc[452]: local: not found [No such file or directory]
/sites/utils/local/bin/abc[453]: local: not found [No such file or directory]
/sites/utils/local/bin/abc[454]: local: not found [No such file or directory]
```

bash xyz.sh     -working fine.
   sh xyz.sh       -working fine.

is there anyway where i can specify to run it as bash or sh from the script itself as this script runs as part of automation.
FYI: Default shell here is ksh :(

Any answer will be highly appricaited.
FYI:  I checked the script for carriage return text /DOS text charater and ran
sed -i 's/\r//' xyz.sh multiple times.

Comment: What does line 452 do? There's probably an option for the command being executed to follow symlinks.

Comment: sorry would like to correct question 
ksh /sites/utils/local/bin/abc - does not work - gives that error mentioned
bash /sites/utils/local/bin/abc -works
sh /sites/utils/local/bin/abc -works

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Faisal : I have put an answer which explains this behavior. Hope it helps :)

Comment: You ran `sed -i 's/\r//' xyz.sh` multiple times. Did it fail, does `head -1 xyz.sh | od -c` still shows a `\r` ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty obvious.
The `ksh` doesn't have the `local` builtin. Check [[ this ]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/local#portability_considerations).

It works with `sh` because `sh` is usually a symlink to `dash` in Ubuntu like systems.

> is there anyway where i can specify to run it as bash or sh from the
>   script itself

Of course yes ! Use a shebang. Put the below stuff in the beginning of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: thanks i see local preceeded with various variables ; example local xyz="some value" , is there any work around for it ?

Comment: If it is not mandatory that you use `ksh` a shebang would solve the problem here.

Comment: i am already using #!/bin/bash here.
 whereis bash
bash: /bin/bash /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz

Answer (score 1):

From you comment to the other answer, I understand that you already have the shebang `#!/bin/bash` in the file `xyz.sh`.

A shebang works only when the script is executed like

```
./xyz.sh
```

When you execute it like

```
ksh xyz.sh
```

The shebang line is ignored and the ksh is use to interpret the script.
Now read the other answer which says the rest.

Comment: That was a nice catch :) . The op may consider making this the accepted answer.

Comment: Forgot to mention i am using /abc  where abc is symlink to xyz.sh

Comment: Thanks the issue resolved when i copied same file from other server.
That still lies the mystery with it .

Answer (score 0):

Many times this happens when you made your script on Windows and after that you uploaded it to LINUX/UNIX.

The problem is that the end of line added by Windows: `CR` `LF` (Windows-Style) is not understood by linux, and it must be changed for the UNIX-Style end of line (`LF`)

Using Notepad++ or whatever, you only need to find `\r\n` (in extended mode) and replace with `\n` and that's all.